# Test code and branch coverage simultanously with Pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest, coverage.py

I am using pytest to test my Python code.

To test for code coverage (C0 coverage) I run `pytest --cov` and I can specify my desired coverage in my `pyproject.toml` file like this:

```
[tool.coverage.report]
fail_under = 95
```

I get this result with a coverage a 96.30%:

```
---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.8.13-final-0 -----------
Name                                                                         Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.....................................

Required test coverage of 95.0% reached. Total coverage: 96.30%
```

To test for branch coverage (C1 coverage)  I run `pytest --cov --cov-branch`. I get this result with a coverage of 95.44%:

```
---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.8.13-final-0 -----------
Name                                                                         Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.....................................

Required test coverage of 95.0% reached. Total coverage: 95.44%
```

I get two different coverage values, so I am testing two different coverage instances. What I would like to do is be able to test for code coverage AND branch coverage with the same command, and also be able to specify two different required coverages.

For now, all I can do is execute pytest two times, with two disadvantages:

1. I have to run my tests 2 times, so it takes twice as long.
2. I am limited to the same required coverage for both.

Comment: I don't understand why line coverage is interesting as a separate metric? Branch coverage gives you all the line information, plus some.

If you do want two separate metrics, you can provide the ``--cov-fail-under=`` option on the pytest command line, the same way you provide ``--cov-branch``

Comment: While it's true that branch coverage provides information about which lines of code branch coverage does provide information about which lines of code have been executed, it doesn't provide all the information that line coverage does. Line coverage can be a useful metric in its own right, and can provide additional insights into how well your code has been tested.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.   Can you give me an example of something line coverage can tell you that branch coverage doesn't?

Comment: It is pretty easy to construct an example where we have a branch coverage that is very high but line coverage is low and vice-versa. Of course, this is not true if the condition for branch coverage is 100%, but this is rarely our chosen threshold. Using both helps to easily see if we're missing something obvious.

Comment: I'd be interested to see an example, so I know if we are talking about the same things.

Comment: For example here: https://codefile.io/f/DkFEs2yBJjm8bnVHBzl5 (stupid code, but it works as an example). Covering all branches but the "important_case" one, you can get ~85% branch coverage, however line coverage will be way lower. And if we only cover the "important_case" branch, we will have the opposite result.

Comment: I should write up exactly how it's calculated, but when coverage.py gives you a total under branch coverage, it is not only the branches that are counted.  The lines are also part of the total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My final solution uses `pytest` to execute the tests, `coverage` to generate coverage reports and [`coverage-threshold`](https://github.com/DeanWay/coverage-threshold) to interpret the results.

From `coverage-theshold`'s README:

> A command line tool for checking coverage reports against configurable coverage minimums. Currently built for use around python's coverage.

Tools to install are: `pytest` (you can also use another test runner), `coverage`, `coverage-threshold`.

I execute:

```
coverage run --branch -m pytest src/  # the --branch argument enables branch coverage
coverage json
coverage-threshold
```

My `pyproject.toml` contains the following lines to configure:

```
[coverage-threshold]
line_coverage_min = 90
file_line_coverage_min = 90
branch_coverage_min = 80
file_branch_coverage_min = 80
```

In order:

- `line_coverage_min` sets a threshold for the line coverage.
- `file_line_coverage_min` sets a threshold for the line coverage to be respected by each file.
- `branch_coverage_min` sets a threshold for the branch coverage.
- `file_branch_coverage_min` sets a threshold for the branch coverage to be respected by each file.

The CLI options are:

```
> coverage-threshold --help
usage: coverage-threshold [-h] [--line-coverage-min LINE_COVERAGE_MIN]
                          [--branch-coverage-min BRANCH_COVERAGE_MIN]
                          [--combined-coverage-min COMBINED_COVERAGE_MIN]
                          [--file-line-coverage-min FILE_LINE_COVERAGE_MIN]
                          [--file-branch-coverage-min FILE_BRANCH_COVERAGE_MIN]
                          [--file-combined-coverage-min FILE_COMBINED_COVERAGE_MIN]
                          [--coverage-json COVERAGE_JSON] [--config CONFIG]

A command line tool for checking coverage reports against configurable coverage minimums

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --line-coverage-min LINE_COVERAGE_MIN
                        minimum global average line coverage threshold
  --branch-coverage-min BRANCH_COVERAGE_MIN
                        minimum global average branch coverage threshold
  --combined-coverage-min COMBINED_COVERAGE_MIN
                        minimum global average combined line and branch coverage threshold
  --file-line-coverage-min FILE_LINE_COVERAGE_MIN
                        the line coverage threshold for each file
  --file-branch-coverage-min FILE_BRANCH_COVERAGE_MIN
                        the branch coverage threshold for each file
  --file-combined-coverage-min FILE_COMBINED_COVERAGE_MIN
                        the combined line and branch coverage threshold for each file
  --coverage-json COVERAGE_JSON
                        path to coverage json (default: ./coverage.json)
  --config CONFIG       path to config file (default: ./pyproject.toml)
```